# Explaning Optimistic Locking Failed Exception after PSQL exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I have a fallowing scenario that I want to understand clearly so I can fix it in a proper way.

Some entity have to be persisted to PostgreSQL database using hibernate. This is the course of events that happens before the errors.

1. Entity attempts to be saved into database (as a part of the logic with a multi-threaded execution). That entity has a `null` character (`0x00`) as a part of it's attribute and I get an exception caused by

   ```
   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
   ```

   because PostgreSQL cannot persist `null` chars, which is OK.
2. That same entity is then modified, but now in a single-threaded environment after the end of a parallel execution of the above mentioned logic and is persisted again to update the database.

   Now I get an Optimistic Locking Failed exception saying that entity has already been saved and that the object is "Stale".

   ```
   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.yc.isystem.business.Offer] with identifier [691909329]:
        optimistic locking failed; nested exception is
        org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.yc.isystem.business.Offer#691909329]
   ```

Can someone explain what happens in the background and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Your entity was loaded in a different transaction in your multithreaded code, that's why it has become *stale*, you'd need to load it anew when you try to update it in your single threaded code which runs in a different transaction

Comment: @Lino but this only happens when first exception is thrown (regarding null char exception), in other situations everything works fine. And is the entity actually saved after  `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00`? I guessed that it wasn't, and after updating it hibernate says that it is stale, which is confusing to me. Is entity actually persisted despite `PSQLException` (0x00 char)?